# Search problem with special characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM "main_parse_user" 
WHERE ("main_parse_user"."bio"::text ~* '\mFounder of JoJoWorld | Python' 
OR "main_parse_user"."first_name"::text ~* '\mFounder of JoJoWorld | Python')
```

I'm looking for text with this code

And sometimes such words with '|'

How can I make it so that '|' treated like a normal line

But with text without such characters, everything works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to escape characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions with a backslash to deprive them of their special meaning.  Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

> `\k` (where `k` is a non-alphanumeric character) matches that character taken as an ordinary character, e.g., `\\` matches a backslash character